# Can I directly get a nested list in my Doctrine result?

Tags: doctrine, php-7, dql, symfony-4.4

Sorry if the question is poorly phrased, I couldn't come up with a good way of describing my issue.

So basically, I'm using the Doctrine query builder to try and a list of training sessions from my `Session` entity. For each `session`, I need to fetch basic properties such as the name and date, but I also need to fetch the list of `participants`. There is a one-to-many relation between the entities `Session` and `Participant`, as there may be several `participants` to a given `session`. I would simply need a list of these `participants`, nested in each item of the list of `sessions`. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "session_name": "name1",
        "session_date": "date1",

        ...

        "participants": [
            {
                "participant_name": "john1",

                ...
            },
            {
                "participant_name": "john2",

                ...
            },

            ...
        ],
    },
    {
        "session_name": "name2",
        "session_date": "date2",

        ...

        "participants": [
            {
                "participant_name": "john3",

                ...
            },
            {
                "participant_name": "john4",

                ...
            },

            ...
        ],
    },

    ...
]
```

This seems to me like it should be quite basic, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work with `JOIN`s, subqueries, etc. The closest I got was this error, which does imply I'm trying to get a nested array (but it won't let me):

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I had this error running this code:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->select('
        s.name,
        s.date,
        (SELECT p.nom FROM '.Participant::class.' p WHERE p.session = s.id) participants
    ')
    ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

I know I could just fetch my `sessions`, then loop through them and fetch their participants with another DQL query, but obviously that doesn't seem like the proper way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want an array and not the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do a `leftJoin` on your `QueryBuilder` :

```
$queryResult = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')

    // After that next line, you can reference participants as 'p'
    ->leftJoin('s.participants', 'p')

    // If you intend to loop on the result, to avoid the N+1 problem, add this line :
    ->addSelect('p')

    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: I have tried `addSelect()`, and it just won't do anything if I already used `select()` beforehands. It feels to me like I'd have to work only with `addSelect()`, which won't let me choose which fields I want to fetch or not. Here I only need the `participant`'s first and last names, so I do not wish to fetch every single field which may be irrelevant in my case (e.g their phone number, address, etc)